# Calculating payments where amounts change per week

Tags: analysis

I have been given the following payment schedule, and must make a weekly payment;

10 Dollars per week for 39 weeks of the year
20 Dollars per week for 13 weeks of the year

How can I calculate the correct or most accurate weekly payment given that I do not know when the payment may start or end.

Comment: Are you asking for the average weekly payment?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw I'm not sure as I currently have the average ((10*39)+(20*13))/52 but I don't feel this to be the most accurate method.

Comment: If you are asking for the constant weekly payment that has the same total over the year as the payment schedule, then the average is correct.

Comment: What do you mean with "correct weekly payment", and what that does that have to do with the weekly payments you have already provided? Why not just stick to them?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw What I am worried about is if a payment schedule is for a year that is fine, but if it stops within the year or only continues for a few months, by using an average there can be an overpayment/underpayment.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean; could you clarify what this "correct weekly payment" is?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw I guess I mean is there a better way than the average.

Comment: @Naz better in what respect?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw Say I was doing this in Excel with a start and and end date, I could program in when the (fixed) 39 weeks of the year are and when the (fixed) 13 weeks of the year are and calculate the average to pay. But given that I don't know when the start and end dates are by using an average I could end up over paying or under paying.

Comment: So are you saying that you don't know when the 13 weeks are? Could you give a specific example of when the average would lead to over/under paying?

Comment: The 13 weeks represent holidays where as the 39 weeks represent working weeks. So if you calculate an average based on 52 weeks ($12.5pw) but the payment schedule starts and stops during only consecutive working weeks ($10pw) you will have made an over payment of $2.5pw for those weeks.